# RegExp match repeated characters

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

For example I have string:

```
 aacbbbqq
```

As the result I want to have following matches:

```
 (aa, c, bbb, qq)
```

I know that I can write something like this:

```
 ([a]+)|([b]+)|([c]+)|...
```

But I think i's ugly and looking for better solution. I'm looking for regular expression solution, not self-written finite-state machines.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can match that with: `(\w)\1*`

Answer (score 26):

`itertools.groupby` is not a RexExp, but it's not self-written either. :-) A quote from python docs:

```
# [list(g) for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCD')] --> AAAA BBB CC D
```

Comment: @Kobi `aaaa bbb aaa`, as expected. Btw it returns list of lists, but it can't be a problem. :-)

Answer (score 26):

#### Generally

The trick is to match a single char of the range you want, and then make sure you match all repetitions of the same character:

```
>>> matcher= re.compile(r'(.)\1*')
```

This matches any single character (`.`) and then its repetitions (`\1*`) if any.

For your input string, you can get the desired output as:

```
>>> [match.group() for match in matcher.finditer('aacbbbqq')]
['aa', 'c', 'bbb', 'qq']
```

NB: because of the match group, `re.findall` won't work correctly.

#### Other ranges

In case you don't want to match *any* character, change accordingly the `.` in the regular expression:

```
>>> matcher= re.compile(r'([a-z])\1*') # only lower case ASCII letters
>>> matcher= re.compile(r'(?i)([a-z])\1*') # only ASCII letters
>>> matcher= re.compile(r'(\w)\1*') # ASCII letters or digits or underscores
>>> matcher= re.compile(r'(?u)(\w)\1*') # against unicode values, any letter or digit known to Unicode, or underscore
```

Check the latter against `u'hello²²'` (Python 2.x) or `'hello²²'` (Python 3.x):

```
>>> text= u'hello=\xb2\xb2'
>>> print('\n'.join(match.group() for match in matcher.finditer(text)))
h
e
ll
o
²²
```

`\w` against non-Unicode strings / bytearrays might be modified if you first have issued a [`locale.setlocale`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale) call.

Answer (score 8):

This will work, see a working example here: http://www.rubular.com/r/ptdPuz0qDV

```
(\w)\1*
```

Comment: :-). Was trying it in Rubular to show an working example, got little late.

Answer (score 5):

The findall method will work if you capture the back-reference like so:

```
result = [match[1] + match[0] for match in re.findall(r"(.)(\1*)", string)]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
re.sub(r"(\w)\1*", r'\1', 'tessst')
```

The output would be:

```
'test'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
import re

string = 'aacbbbqq'
result = re.findall(r'((\w)\2*?)', string)
output = [x[0] for x in result]

print(output)
```

Output will be :

```
['aa', 'c', 'bbb', 'qq']
```