# How to define a separator in string using regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I want a string, which must be in parentheses `()` and separated with a comma `,` something like: `(aaa),(bbbb),(cccccccc)`

How could I match that using regular expression?

Comment: Wish there was a regular expression to fix typos!

Comment: Whats "allowed" to be in between the () ?

Comment: You can use the pattern ^\([^(^)]+\)(,\([^(^)]+\))*$  Try for your self: https://regex101.com/r/cJj2ky/1

Answer (score 6):

You can try this

```
^(?!,)(,?\(\w+\))+$
```

---

`^` marks the beginning of string

`$` marks the end of string

Both `^`,`$` are required else it would match in between

`\w+` matches 1 to many of [a-zA-Z\d_]

`,?` would optionally match `,`

`^(?!,)` would look for `,` at the beginning of string and if it finds it,it doesn't match further.If it doesn't find,it returns to the previous position i.e at the start of string

Comment: This will also accept a string starting with a comma though.  ",(aaa)" would be accepted.

Comment: @Vahlkron just realized it..edited the ans

Comment: Yeah, this will work now.  Good one Anirudh!  +1

Comment: Actually, it looks like it's accepting a comma inside the () also.  "(,sdfs),(sdfsd)" is valid.

Comment: @Vahlkron you can change `.*?` to `\w+`

Comment: Ahh I see that now.  Nicely done.

Comment: This regex would also matches `(aaa)(bbbb)(cccccccc)`

Answer (score 0):

This regex

```
\(([^\)])\)
```

will match everything that's inside parethenses. You can use it to find submatches or whatever you need.

I suggest you first tokenize, saving in different variables what's separated by commas, and then use the regular expression to match what's inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
/^\(([^)])\1*\)(?:,\(([^)])\2*\))*$/
```

using [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for the [repeated characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6306098/1048572), escaped parenthesis around them, and allowing it to be followed by the same thing [many times](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) - delimited with commata. Altogether [anchored](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) on the whole string.