# How to find double occurrence of a letter in a word

Tags: python

I have string :-

```
s = 'bubble'
```

how to use regular expression to get a list like:

```
['b', 'u', 'bb', 'l', 'e']
```

I want to filter single as well as double occurrence of a letter.

Comment: See the following SO post; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306098/regexp-match-repeated-characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really have two questions. The first question is how to split the list, the second is how to filter.

The splitting takes advantage of back references in a pattern. In this case we'll construct a pattern the will find one or two occurrences of a letter then construct a list from the search results. The \1 in the code block refers to the first parenthesized expression.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'(.)\1?')
s = "bubble"
result = [x.group() for x in pattern.finditer(s)]
print(result)
```

To filter the list stored in `result` you could use a list comprehension that filters on length.

```
filtered_result = [x for x in result if len(x) == 2]
print(filtered_result)
```

You could just get the set of duplications directly by tweaking the regular expression.

```
pattern2 = re.compile(r'(.)\1')
result2 = [x.group() for x in pattern2.finditer(s)]
print(result2)
```

The output from running the above is:

```
['b', 'u', 'bb', 'l', 'e']
['bb']
['bb']
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
import re

[m.group(0) for m in re.finditer('(.)\\1*',s)]
```

For 'bubbles' this returns:

```
['b', 'u', 'bb', 'l', 'e', 's']
```

For 'bubblesssss' this returns:

```
['b', 'u', 'bb', 'l', 'e', 'sssss']
```

Comment: if you only want to find double occurrence, you can use ? instead of * in the regex. You can also use a raw string instead of having to escape the backslash.