# Get a number of repeated sequences in string

Tags: javascript, regex, for-loop, repeat

For example, I have a following string that consists of 0 and 1: `1010101101` or anything close to it. How am I able to count number of all repeated 3-number sequences of elements in it? 
Simple split and regex doesn’t seem to work because when I search for number of repeats of `101` it doesn’t get the right amount.
So I guess I need some method to manually iterate through the string with for loop and if’s to check every possible combination. Is there a way to make it faster in case there are much more numbers?
I haven’t found any question like that at stackoverflow so I guess it’s not a duplicate.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which exactly sequences? Any?

Comment: [RegExp match repeated characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306098/regexp-match-repeated-characters) maybe help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead regex pattern:

```js
var temp = "00111010101101";
var count = (temp.match(/(?=101)/g) || []).length;
console.log(count);
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/JAvzvv/1

Comment: `"00111010101101".split(101).length - 1` does the same

Comment: @Slim, no, it doesn’t. In my case it ignores one “101” because it goes right after the previous one.

Comment: So `"10101"` should return 2 not 1 ?