# Compute maximum number of consecutive identical integers in array column

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

Consider the following:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    [0, [1, 1, 4, 4, 4]],
    [1, [3, 2, 2, -4]],
    [2, [1, 1, 5, 5]],
    [3, [-1, -9, -9, -9, -9]]]
    ,
    ['id', 'array_col']
)

df.show()
'''
+---+--------------------+
| id|           array_col|
+---+--------------------+
|  0|     [1, 1, 4, 4, 4]|
|  1|       [3, 2, 2, -4]|
|  2|        [1, 1, 5, 5]|
|  3|[-1, -9, -9, -9, -9]|
+---+--------------------+
'''
```

The desired result would be:

```
'''
+---+--------------------+-------------------------+
| id|           array_col|max_consecutive_identical|
+---+--------------------+-------------------------+
|  0|     [1, 1, 4, 4, 4]|                        3|
|  1|       [3, 2, 2, -4]|                        2|
|  2|        [1, 1, 5, 5]|                        2|
|  3|[-1, -9, -9, -9, -9]|                        4|
+---+--------------------+-------------------------+
'''
```

I've tried solving it by joining the array as a string, then doing a `regexp_extract_all` according to the regex I found here [RegExp match repeated characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306098/regexp-match-repeated-characters).

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat_ws, expr

df = df.withColumn('joined_str', concat_ws('', col('array_col')))
df.show()
'''
+---+--------------------+-----------+
| id|           array_col| joined_str|
+---+--------------------+-----------+
|  0|     [1, 1, 4, 4, 4]|      11444|
|  1|       [3, 2, 2, -4]|      322-4|
|  2|        [1, 1, 5, 5]|       1155|
|  3|[-1, -9, -9, -9, -9]| -1-9-9-9-9|
+---+--------------------+-----------+
'''

df = df.withColumn('regexp_extracted', expr('regexp_extract_all(joined_str, "([0-9])\1*", 1)'))
df.show()
'''
+---+--------------------+----------+----------+----------------+
| id|           array_col| concat_ws|joined_str|regexp_extracted|
+---+--------------------+----------+----------+----------------+
|  0|     [1, 1, 4, 4, 4]|     11444|     11444| [1, 1, 4, 4, 4]|
|  1|       [3, 2, 2, -4]|     322-4|     322-4|    [3, 2, 2, 4]|
|  2|        [1, 1, 5, 5]|      1155|      1155|    [1, 1, 5, 5]|
|  3|[-1, -9, -9, -9, -9]|-1-9-9-9-9|-1-9-9-9-9| [1, 9, 9, 9, 9]|
+---+--------------------+----------+----------+----------------+
'''
```

But then I got stuck because of 3 problems:

- Negative numbers would be a problem to match
- Numbers with more the 1 digit would be a problem to match
- Even if all numbers were between 0-9, the regex doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [aggregate](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.5.0/api/sql/index.html#aggregate) to iterate over the arrays and collect the required information:

```python
df.withColumn('max_consecutive_identical', F.expr("""
    aggregate(
        array_col,
        (cast(1 as bigint), cast(1 as bigint), cast(null as bigint)),
        (acc, x) -> (
            if(acc.col3 = x, acc.col1 + 1, cast(1 as bigint)), 
            if(acc.col3 = x and acc.col1 + 1 > acc.col2, acc.col1 + 1, acc.col2), 
            x)
    ).col2""")).show()
```

The idea is to use a struct of 3 bigints (with elements named `col1`, `col2` and `col3`) as `acc` variable.

- `col3`: contains the array element seen in the previous iteration
- `col1`: counter of how many values of `x` we have seen so far. Will be reset to 1 if the current value and the previous value do not match
- `col2`: the maximum of all `col1` values seen so far.
  After the last iteration, `col2` contains the maximum number of consecutive identical integers in the array.

Output:

```
+---+--------------------+-------------------------+
| id|           array_col|max_consecutive_identical|
+---+--------------------+-------------------------+
|  0|     [1, 1, 4, 4, 4]|                        3|
|  1|       [3, 2, 2, -4]|                        2|
|  2|        [1, 1, 5, 5]|                        2|
|  3|[-1, -9, -9, -9, -9]|                        4|
+---+--------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: max_consecutive_identical should be 1 if value is not repeated: `(cast(1 as bigint), cast(1 as bigint), cast(null as bigint))`

Comment: @L.B. you are right. I have fixed my code

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this function instead of regular expressions:

```py
def max_consequtive(arr):
    retval = []
    running_value = None; running_count = 0;
    for running_item in arr:
        if running_value != running_item:
            if running_count != 0:
                retval.append(running_count)
            running_value = running_item; running_count = 1
        else:
             running_count += 1
    retval.append(running_count)
    return max(retval)

## Test

max_consequtive([-1, -9, -9, -9, -9])
4
max_consequtive([3, 2, 2, -4])
2
```